# Powermock+JUnit - NullPointerException with new class

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

Getting NullPointerException when I try to mock a method and that method has a local variable with new class. Tried different way, but no luck. Please see the comments, I have mentioned what I tried and where I am getting exception.

Thanks in advance!

```
    @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
    @PrepareForTest(StudentController.class)
    public class StudentControllerTest {
        @Mock
        HttpServletRequest request;

        @Mock
        StudentService studentService;

        @InjectMocks
        StudentController studentController;
        @Test
        public void create() {
            Student student =mock(Student.class);
            **// Also tried Student student = new Student();**
            student.setName("Name");
            student.setAddress("New York");

            when(studentService.create(student)).thenReturn(student);
            // if I try below code I am getting compile error - Type mismatch: cannot convert from Matcher<Student> to Student
 //when(studentService.create(any(Student.class))).thenReturn(student);
            Student createdStudent= studentController("Name", "New York", 1);
            assertTrue(0 < createdStudent.getStudentId())
        }
    }
```

**Studentcontroller.java**

```
@PostMapping("/api/student/create")
public Student create(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam("name") String name, @RequestParam("address") String address, @RequestParam("grade") String grade) {

    Student student = new Student();
    try {
        student.setName(name);
        student.setAddress(address);
        student.setGrade(Integer.decode(grade));

        student = studentService.create(student);
        **// Throwing NullPointer in this line. I did dubug and can see student returned is null**
        message = "Successfully Created Student[" + student.getId() + "] " + name;  

    } catch (Exception e) {
        message = "Exception while create the student: " + name;
        log.error(message + "\n" + StackTraceUtil.getStackTrace(e));
        student.setErrorMessage(message);
    }

    return student;
}
```

**SOLUTION:**

I was using `org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.any`  That gives compile error `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Matcher<Student> to Student`

Now I changed it to `org.mockito.ArgumentMatcher.any`
You can either one of below two. Both will work.

The key was importing `org.mockito.ArgumentMatcher.any`

```
Student student =mock(Student.class);
student.setName("Name");
student.setAddress("New York");
```

OR

```
Student student = new Student();
student.setName("Name");
student.setAddress("New York");
```

Comment: Did you include the `@RunWith(runner-goes-here)` annotation in your test class?

Comment: Make sure a mocked studentService exists and is being properly injected.

Comment: Show us your entire `StudentControllerTest` class please

Comment: Based on the method under test, the tight coupling to `new Student()` and the fact that the matcher setup in the test wont match the one created in the method under test, then `studentService.create` will return null.

Comment: @Nkosi - I was thinking so as well. any solution without changing the Controller, I mean only changing the test class ?

Comment: No need for a Student mock. Use a more flexible matcher like `any(Student.class)`, capture the passed argument in the setup and set the desired id so the method under test can flow to completion.

Comment: Otherwise the use powermock to mock the creation of the student. In that case then most of what you already have for the test would remain the same. Not a big fan of that workaround though as it encourages bad design.

Comment: @Nkosi - I tried any(Student.class), but I was getting compile error. Let me try again and will keep you posted about the exact compile error.

Comment: Ok hold on let me see if I can draft up something here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the method under test, the tight coupling to new Student() and the fact that the matcher setup in the test wont match the one created in the method under test, then `studentService.create` will return *null*.

There really is no need for a `Student` mock since the method under test is already creating one.

Use a more flexible argument matcher like `any(Student.class)`, capture the passed argument in the setup and set the desired id so the method under test can flow to completion.

For example

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(StudentController.class)
public class StudentControllerTest {
    @Mock
    HttpServletRequest request;

    @Mock
    StudentService studentService;

    @InjectMocks
    StudentController studentController;

    @Test
    public void create() {
        //Arrange
        int expectedId = 1;
        when(studentService.create(any(Student.class)))
            .thenAnswer(i -> {
                Student student = (Student)i.getArguments()[0];
                //manipulate the student as needed.
                //Like setting an id

                //...student.setId(expectedId)

                return student;
            });

        //Act
        Student createdStudent = studentController.create(request, "Name", "New York", 1);

        //Assert
        assertTrue(createdStudent != null);
        assertTrue(expectedId == createdStudent.getStudentId());
    }
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate your time to help me. I tried your solution, I am getting the same error (Typemissmatch) as I mentioned in the comment in my question code.

Comment: and I may get error in cobertura as it doesn't understand lambda

Comment: I got it. I have been using org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.any. Now I changed it to org.mockito.ArgumentMatcher.any. No other changes required in my code. I updated the solution in my question